# How get keycloak token?

Tags: node.js, api, keycloak

I'm making a bot, and i have to make requests to a GraphQL API and it's protected with Keycloak. I initialized it like in the documentation [of this site](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/securing_apps/topics/oidc/nodejs-adapter.html)

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
const session = require('express-session');


var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
},
{
  url: "https://host.com",
  realm: "app-realm",
  clientId: "app-clientId"
})
```

And when i'm going to make queries i need the token to pass it in the header, but don't know how to get this token.

```
 const fetch = require('node-fetch');
 var token = ''; // this is what i dont know how to get 
 var bearer = 'Bearer ' + token;


fetch("https://api-host/graphql",{
    method:'POST',
    headers:  {
      'Authorization': bearer,
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
             },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
      {
        services{
          name
        }
      }
      `
    
    }),
  
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {console.log(data)} )
```

Comment: If your keycloak client is confidential then you can create an access token using `client_id` and `client_secret` and if your client is public then you can generate an access token using OAuth  code grant flow,

Comment: How should I create the token with client_id and client_secret

Comment: It worked thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your keycloak client is confidential then you can create an access token using `client_id` and `client_secret` and if your client is public then you can generate an access token using OAuth code grant flow

You can create an access token using the token end point.

Sample cURL :

```
curl --request POST --url https://authserver/auth/realms/yourrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   --data 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret'
```